# Why is huge data shuffling in Spark when using union()/coalesce(1,false) on DataFrame?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd, shuffle

I have Spark job which does some processing on ORC data and stores back ORC data using DataFrameWriter save() API introduced in Spark 1.4.0. I have the following piece of code which is using heavy shuffle memory. How do I optimize below code? Is there anything wrong with it? It is working fine as expected only causing slowness because of GC pause and shuffles lots of data so hitting memory issues. I am new to Spark.

```
JavaRDD<Row> updatedDsqlRDD = orderedFrame.toJavaRDD().coalesce(1, false).map(new Function<Row, Row>() {
   @Override
   public Row call(Row row) throws Exception {
        List<Object> rowAsList;
        Row row1 = null;
        if (row != null) {
          rowAsList = iterate(JavaConversions.seqAsJavaList(row.toSeq()));
          row1 = RowFactory.create(rowAsList.toArray());
        }
        return row1;
   }
}).union(modifiedRDD);
DataFrame updatedDataFrame = hiveContext.createDataFrame(updatedDsqlRDD,renamedSourceFrame.schema());
updatedDataFrame.write().mode(SaveMode.Append).format("orc").partitionBy("entity", "date").save("baseTable");
```

### Edit

As per suggestion I tried to convert above code into the following using `mapPartitionsWithIndex`() but I still see data shuffling it is better than above code but still it fails by hitting GC limit and throws OOM or goes into GC pause for long and timeout and YARN will kill executor.

I am using spark.storage.memoryFraction as 0.5 and spark.shuffle.memoryFraction as 0.4; I tried to use default and changed many combinations, but nothing helped.

```
JavaRDD<Row> indexedRdd = sourceRdd.cache().mapPartitionsWithIndex(new Function2<Integer, Iterator<Row>, Iterator<Row>>() {
            @Override
            public Iterator<Row> call(Integer ind, Iterator<Row> rowIterator) throws Exception {
                List<Row> rowList = new ArrayList<>();

                while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                    Row row = rowIterator.next();
                    List<Object> rowAsList = iterate(JavaConversions.seqAsJavaList(row.toSeq()));
                    Row updatedRow = RowFactory.create(rowAsList.toArray());
                    rowList.add(updatedRow);
                }           
                return rowList.iterator();
            }
        }, true).coalesce(200,true);
```

Comment: Hi @Holden I have changed code as per your suggestion please see edit in the question but still not able to solve shuffling and OOM

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Coalescing an RDD or Dataframe to a single partition means that all your processing is happening on a single machine. This is not a good thing for a variety of reasons: all of the data has to be shuffled across the network, there is no more parallelism, etc. Instead you should look at other operators like reduceByKey, mapPartitions, or really pretty much anything besides coalescing the data to a single machine.

Note: looking are your code I don't see *why* you are bringing it down to a single machine, you can probably just remove that part.

Comment: Hi Holden thanks I have complex use case which forces me to work on one partition serially because of strict order processing of rows if I don't use coalesce multiple machine will have different order of data and my results won't be correct above code works very well just not scaling it. BTW I am using coalesce(1,false) shuffle false still why is it doing shuffling?

Comment: Shuffle false only means that it won't support growing the number of partitions (from the scaladoc: 

However, if you're doing a drastic coalesce, e.g. to numPartitions = 1, this may result in your computation taking place on fewer nodes than you like (e.g. one node in the case of numPartitions = 1). To avoid this, you can pass shuffle = true. This will add a shuffle step, but means the current upstream partitions will be executed in parallel (per whatever the current partitioning is).)

Comment: That being said, you may actually get better performance with shuffle=true. If you really need to process one partition at a time, you may be better looking at the code in toLocalIterator (along with a cache) (note: don't actually use toLocalIterator just look at its implementation for an idea) and then structure your code to use mapPartitionsWithIndex and filter for one partition then execute that operation with foreach in a loop. This will allow you to avoid bringing the data back to a single node which is likely a large source of your problems.

Comment: With the final note that your best bet to improve performance here is figuring out a way to relax your constraints so that you don't need to do row-at-a-time processing. Best of luck!

Comment: Hi Holden thanks much I will try coalesce(1,true) rest of the things I cant change because of serial processing row by row based on sequence column I have. Like you said coalesce(1,true) should work better and keeping my results correct let me try.

Comment: I'd really recommend also looking at the toLocalIterator code and how it uses mapPartitionsWithIndex + filter and iteration to process your data one record at a time without having to transfer the data. Adding true to coalesce will only do so much and the other approach allows the data to still be distributed on many nodes.

Comment: Sure Holden I will try toLocalIterator for sure for time being I will want to move on with shuffle true. Thanks much.

Comment: To be clear, don't use toLocalIterator, do something _like_ it (as described in the comments). best of luck and hopefully one of the simpler things works so you don't have go with the more complicated approach.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88865/discussion-between-user449355-and-holden).